# What encryption/compression is this, and how to encode/decode from it?

Tags: encryption, decompress, function-hooking, sniffing

I've been trying to reverse engineer an Android app's communication protocol using a combination of Xposed and Packet sniffing. 
Most of the packets the app sends have this header set:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

which leads me to beleive it is some sort of byte array. The sniffed packet body is encoded in something I do not recognize, but thanks to Xposed, I can get the decoded version. This is what I receive from the server: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2koqy.png (raw data is at http://bit.ly/2g5JKgH ). I've tried various ways of decoding it to no avail. After hooking some methods in Xposed which receive the final, decoded data, I found that the decoded version of the data I was sniffing is this:

```
{"miis":[{"owner_player_id":"12bea2c3d7654b66","position":"12bea2c3d7654b66"}],"SAKASHO_CURRENT_ASSET_REVISION":"","SAKASHO_CURRENT_MASTER_REVISION":"b324a24d2cf7cd0effb2941e9f5e515456e9e82d","SAKASHO_CURRENT_DATE_TIME":1480231467}
```

I'm not sure how it got decoded, but I have some clues.
First, the encoded packet has a size of 183 bytes, while the decoded version has a size of 231 bytes. This leads me to believe it's using some sort of compression. The client also sends an Accept-Encoding: gzip to the server which supports this, but after decoding it using gzip, I still get unreadable data, which I think means there is some sort of encryption going on. Looking at the app's code, translated from smali into a rough java equivalent, this is the method that supposedly takes in a byte array and spits out a String

```
public static String a(byte[] bArr) {
        if (bArr == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return new String(bArr, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't happen!", e);
        }
    }
```

however, while trying to replicate this in my own Java program, I always get the original strange character representation of the data.

What I'm wondering is, how does the original packet data get to the final, uncompressed json structure, and if it's a general encoding method, or one the app developers made themselves.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Xposed open source and/or does it have a "verbose" flag so you can see what it's doing?

Comment: Xposed is [open source](https://github.com/rovo89/Xposed), but it is not the app i'm trying to reverse engineer, it's what i'm using to see what that encrypted text turns into, by hooking methods in the app I am looking at